# How to build node.js and ejs file for deploying on 000webhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ejs, web-hosting

I have a basic todo-app created using node.js and ejs templating.

I want to host it using 000webhost(a free web-hosting service). I've already hosted a react app for free using this, for that I did `"npm run build"`. That made the react app convert into couple of files. That was easy to deploy.

How do I do the same (or something similar) with this node.js and ejs app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achieve this, you need to use paid version of 000webhost. 000webhost free version is not available for node js. Thank you!